# How to combine express and angular routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm trying to combined Jade AngularJS together with ExpressJS. I had an app.js for express to run the server with Grunt. From that app.js I render home.jade which directs me to the home page. Inside the homepage, I had angularJS. I created another app.js in AngularJS directory. How do I combine the routes together?

**App.js (Express)**

```
var config = require('./config/config');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var oneDay = 86400000;
app.use(express.static(config.root + '/public', { maxAge: oneDay }));

app.set('views', config.root + '/app/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('home');
});
app.listen(config.port);
```

**App.js (AngularJS)**

```
var myApp = angular.module("app", []);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');

    $routeProvider
        .when('/haha', {
            title: '',
            templateUrl: '{DIR_TO_JADE_FILE}',
            controller: 'HomeController'
    })    
});

myApp.controller("AppController", function AppController($scope, $http, $location, $window, $rootScope) {
    alert("Initialize...");
    $scope.message = "HELLO";
});
```

**HTML**

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
 head
  meta(charset='UTF-8')
  meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0')
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='css/vendor/simple-line-icons.css')
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='css/vendor/tooltipster.css')
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='css/vendor/owl.carousel.css')
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='css/style.css')
  //- favicon
  link(rel='icon', href='favicon.ico')
  title Random | Home
 body(ng-controller="AppController")
  block content
  include content
  include angularJS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thumb rule for routing on front end and back end :

**Back end routing :** 
Routes defined to fetch/update data.

**Front end routing :** 
Routes defined as per the page which shall be shown to user.

So lets say we have two pages , home page and profile page

so, front end routes will have two pages

*"/home" loading home page
"/profile" loading profile*

now on each of the page, you would need to show some data inside the html page, for which you make routes :

*"/getHomePageData" route to return some news feed (lets say)
"/getProfilePageData" route to return some user related information*

Now on each page, on success of server route call, you need to pass those data in html to show it to user.

Agreed there are exceptions/conventions, like using jade template to send compiled page ( page with data embed).